# Python - Whitespace after

Tags: python, python-3.x, whitespace

Why is there a white space that outputs when I print something like this in Python 3?
(Is it in the `'\n'` character itself?)

```
print (my_var1, '\n', my_var_2)
```

Output :

```
1
 2
```

I know how to fix it. It is not that complicated, but i was just wondering why...

Comment: If you pass multiple arguments to `print`, it puts a space between each one. Try specifying the `sep` keyword argument

Comment: It's the seperation character `print (my_var1, '\n', my_var_2, sep="")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`print` adds a single space (or the value of the `sep` keyword argument) after *every* argument, including `\n'. You might want combine the three strings into a single argument yourself.

```
print(my_var1 + '\n' + my_var2)
```

or

```
print('\n'.join([my_var1, my_var2]))
```

Better than either of theses would be to use the `format` string method:

```
print('{}\n{}'.format(my_var1, my_var2))
```

which both handles conversion to `str` if necessary and eliminates any temporary objects.

I would prefer, though, setting `sep` to `\n` as in @billy's answer.

Comment: These examples are not necessarily equivalent to the OPs example, because the vars won't implicitly be cast to `str`s.

Comment: I don't see that as a huge problem. If they aren't strings, then they should be explicitly converted (and the caller should be aware of whether the arguments are strings or not).

Comment: On the other hand, using `format` addresses that issue and would probably be preferable to either of my hasty suggestions.

Comment: Certainly it's not a *huge* problem, but I figured it  was worth pointing out since I've encountered many non-Python people who can't get why `print(x, '\n', y)` will work for non-strings, but `print(x + ' \n ' + y)` won't.

Answer (score 6):

When you have multiple positional arguments in the `print` function, it writes the `str` form of those arguments with the `sep` string between them - which in the default case is one space (`' '`).  There are many ways to print two variables on two separate lines.

```
print(my_var1)
print(my_var2)
```

or

```
for var in (my_var1, my_var2):
    print(var)
```

or

```
print(my_var1, my_var2, sep='\n')
```

or the myriad of other examples here.

Comment: I realized after I stepped away from my computer that your third option is probably the best (no temporary string objects need to be created just to pass as an argument.)

Comment: Thanks!  Although if the exercise is simply "print two variables on two lines", then I think the first is the best because of the simplicity and that it doesn't require any extra knowledge of the `print` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiline comments and f-string

```
my_var1, my_var_2 = 1,2
print (f"""{my_var1}
{my_var_2}""")
```

gives

```
1
2

[Program finished]
```

Although my personal favourite is

```
my_var1, my_var_2 = 1,2
varlist = [my_var1, my_var_2] 

for var in (varlist):
    print(var)
```

simply bcos you can have n variables which you can put in list and then print using loop